# Notation in a Cauchy problem with boundary periodic conditions.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

My question is in the second line that I marked, where there is $u(t,\cdot)$.What is the meaning of that $\cdot$?
[image]

Comment: Could just be, for any fixed $t$, a function that maps $x\mapsto u(t,x)$.

Comment: I think it is for any fixed $x$.

Comment: @AndresBravo: No, Stinking Bishop is right.

Comment: Thanks... I understand now